# Is it possible to do the following transformation in SQL?

Tags: sql

Suppose I have the following values for match_id

1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3...

Is it possible to use SQL to convert to the following values

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...

In other words list all match_id in sequential order.  For the first value perform the following operation

firstvalue * 2 - 1

For the second value perform the following operation

secondvalue * 2

Comment: And the 3rd Value? the rule is unclear for me.

Comment: Are those values in separate rows?

Comment: Please include the RDMS engine in post or tags in the future.  Thanks!

Comment: The values are in separate rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** This was written for SQL Server.

```
select
    case when (row_number() over (order by match_id)) % 2 = 1
         then match_id * 2 - 1
         else match_id * 2
    end as output_value
from
    myTable
```

**Edit 2:** To update the rows, you can use the following:

```
update
    T
set match_id =
    case when RowNumber % 2 = 1
         then match_id * 2 - 1
         else match_id * 2
    end
from
    (select
        *,
        (row_number() over (order by match_id)) as RowNumber
    from myTable) T
```

Comment: The OP must remember that this works in limited number of RDBMS. This worksat least on Oracle and Postgresql but not on MySQL, HSQLDB, or such (as far as I know)

Comment: Is there an analogous version using update instead of select?

Answer (score 0):

For a purely sequential numbering, this will do

```
;with TMP as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by match_id) rownum
    from myTable)
UPDATE TMP
SET match_id = rownum
```